# How often does the browser transmit the authorization token during a SOS session?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, identityserver4, openid

Consider a SOS (Single Sign On) situation in which a participant site forwards the browser to an authentication portal that uses an identity server to authenticate and return a token.

I know this token is usually persisted for the rest of the user's browsing session, but I'm interested in the specifics of where this token is persisted and when it is transmitted in terms of actual requests and responses.

Does the browser embed it in the header of its requests and pass it in every time it requests a page/resource?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your implementation, may be in localstorage or in sessionstorage. Browser doesn't any thing about token, like send on any request. You should handle storage, refresh token and send on each requests by your own code, our use exist packages like angular-oauth2-oisc which does all of your need together with some simple configs.